# button click in Selenium in element img

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to test an image button click in Selenium.

The image is the event, when I click the sgt message appears me

HTML CODE:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a href="m_ConsultaVehicular.aspx">
    <img src="../Images/ico_cons_vehi.png" alt="Consulta Vehicular">     
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a href="m_ConsultaEstadoTitulos.aspx">
        <img src="../Images/ico_cons_titulos.png" alt="Consulta Estado de Títulos">
    </a>
</td>
```

```
      BaseUrl = "https://www.sunarp.gob.pe/"
        UrlDirection= BaseUrl + "seccion/servicios/detalles/0/c3.html"
        path_to_chromedriver = '/home/developer/lear-seleniun/chromedriver' # change path as needed
        browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
        browser.get(UrlDirection)
   submit=browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("//a[contains(@href,'Consulta Vehicular')]/img")).click();
```

Comment: add code to question

Comment: Please check again

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple issues.

1. You have a space in `'Consulta Vehicular'` when one doesn't exist in the `href`.
2. You are using `By.cssSelector()` but your supplied string is an XPath. Just change the call to `By.xpath()`.

A minor point... all you need to do is click the `A`, you don't need to click the `IMG` itself so I removed that part of the XPath. I tested the code below and it's working.

```
browser.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'ConsultaVehicular')]")).click();
```